# How to set incremental xapth for newly added rows of a webtable using robot framework/python/selenium?

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I came across a certain requirement: I have a web table where new rows are added daily.

I want to write an automation script in Robot Framework-Python-Selenium-Eclipse-RedEditor Plugin. Right now, I am able to get the total rows count of the table and able to get the text of particular column.

**My requirement**

I want to go to a specific newly added row and check the particular text. As I need to automate it the newly added rows xpath would be incremental so how to automate that?

```
 ${rows} =  get element count   xpath=//*[@id="tableData"]/tbody/tr
 log to console   Total Rows= ${rows}
 
 ${nameColumn}=  get text   xpath=//*[@id="tableData"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[9] 
 log to console   name is =  ${nameColumn}
```

If 5, 6, 7 rows are getting added then xpath would be incremental like

```
xpath=//*[@id="tableData"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[9]
xpath=//*[@id="tableData"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[9]
```

I want to write the script in a way that every time a new **row** (or **rows**) gets added in the table then if I just run the script it will check xpath for newly added rows and go incremental till last rows and  read and returned its data from mentioned columns.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you share the html properties of newly old and added rows?

Comment: Hi, What details exactly you need?

Comment: In order to see how a new row has been added every time, we need the HTML DOM structure. Guess, it might contain some different class names. 

If there is only one row added at the end and you want only that then you can use `xpath=//*[@id="tableData"]/tbody/tr[last()]/td[9]`

Comment: Where to check that. With F12 you want outer html or how?

Comment: Yes, With F12-> Elements> Locate table element > Right click and copy element.

Answer (score 0):

There're more ways how to achieve this, I'll show you one.

First, you need to be able to store the current number of rows somewhere. So one obvious solution is to write the number to a file to a disk. For that you'd need `OperatingSystem` library.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem
```

Let's set a variable that stores the name of the file, so it's not hard-coded anywhere later on:

```
*** Variables ***
${file_name}=    last_row.txt
```

Next, you need to consider that the file might not exist when you run your script for the first time. You don't want your script to fail in such a situation:

```
*** Keywords ***
Touch If Does Not Exist
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Get File    ${file_name}
    Run Keyword If    ${status} == ${False}    Touch    ${file_name}
```

Again, I'm using `OperatingSystem` library. Check the documentation [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html).

Now, you might want to prepare two other keywords, one for leading the last row number from the file and one for saving the last row number into the file:

```
Load From File
    Touch If Does Not Exist
    ${content}=    Get File    ${file_name}    
    @{lines}=    Split to lines    ${content}
    ${len}=    Get Length    ${lines}
    ${row_number}=    Run Keyword If    ${len} > 0    Get From List    ${lines}    0    ELSE    Set Variable    0    
    [Return]    ${row_number}   

Save Into File
    [Arguments]    ${last_row_number}
    ${last_row_number}=    Convert To String    ${last_row_number}
    Create File    ${file_name}    ${last_row_number}
```

Notice that I'm using `Split Into Lines` keyword from `String` library and `Get From List` keyword from `Collections` library. Check the documentation [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html) and [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html). So I need to update imports:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem    
Library    Collections 
Library    String
```

Finally your test case that I simplified because I don't have your webpage where I could actually try it out:

```
*** Test Cases *** 
Increment Over Rows
    ${start_row_number}=    Load From File
    ${total_rows}=    Evaluate    ${start_row_number} + 5
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${start_row_number}    ${total_rows}
        Log    ${i}
    END
    Save Into File    ${total_rows}
```

You'd need to change this line:

```
${total_rows}=    Evaluate    ${start_row_number} + 5
```

to a line where you get the actual number of rows in your table, so perhaps you can use keyword `Get Element Count` from `Selenium` library.

Just to summarize with a complete working example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem    
Library    Collections 
Library    String       

*** Variables ***
${file_name}=    last_row.txt

*** Keywords ***
Touch If Does Not Exist
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Get File    ${file_name}
    Run Keyword If    ${status} == ${False}    Touch    ${file_name}           

Load From File
    Touch If Does Not Exist
    ${content}=    Get File    ${file_name}    
    @{lines}=    Split to lines    ${content}
    ${len}=    Get Length    ${lines}
    ${row_number}=    Run Keyword If    ${len} > 0    Get From List    ${lines}    0    ELSE    Set Variable    0    
    [Return]    ${row_number}   

Save Into File
    [Arguments]    ${last_row_number}
    ${last_row_number}=    Convert To String    ${last_row_number}
    Create File    ${file_name}    ${last_row_number}

*** Test Cases *** 
Increment Over Rows
    ${start_row_number}=    Load From File
    ${total_rows}=    Evaluate    ${start_row_number} + 5
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${start_row_number}    ${total_rows}
        Log    ${i}
    END
    Save Into File    ${total_rows}
```

When I run the script for the first time, a file will be created with number 5 in it, after another execution, the file will contain 10, then 15 and so on. It should work fine. I'll leave you to implementation details regarding your actual DOM. I suppose the biggest trouble was to find out how to store the number of rows somewhere and load it next time, which I showed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check this but I feel it looks bit complex. Cant we set rows xpath as variable and add increment to it by anyway? Because I need to add another script inside it to track the process of uploading of some data which will resulted into addition of new row/rows.

Comment: If I understood your requirement, you want to be able to persist the row count between executions of your script. Therefore, you need a mechanism to store the row count somewhere till the next time because you want to increment only over **new** rows, not over all rows in your table. If I misunderstood, feel free to point it out and perhaps I can correct my answer.

Comment: I got your logic, I will implement it in my script and check and update accordingly.

Comment: I checked that but its not working. Let me know if you have any other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @Amaze_Rock: my example works for what it was intended for, but you need to apply it to your concrete problem with the actual DOM. If something on your side doesn't work, you need to first debug it line by line, then understand every single line, and if you still need help, you need to provide concrete information on what doesn't work, where it doesn't work, what the error message is etc.